# use dplyr with missing data

Tags: r, dplyr

Once again a continuation of my previous 2 questions, but a slightly different problem. Another wrinkle in the data I have been working with:

```
date <- c("2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24",
          "2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24")
location <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,"out","out")
sensor <- c(1,16,1,16,1,16,1,1,16)
Temp <- c(35,34,92,42,21,47,42,63,12)
df <- data.frame(date,location,sensor,Temp)
```

Some of my data have missing values. They are not indicated by `NA`. They are just not in the data period.

I want to subtract location "out" from location "4" ignoring the other locations and I want to do it by date and sensor. I have successfully done this with data locations that have all the data with the following code

```
df %>%
  filter(location %in% c(4, 'out')) %>% 
  group_by(date, sensor) %>% 
  summarize(Diff = Temp[location=="4"] - Temp[location=="out"],
            location = first(location)) %>%
  select(1, 2, 4, 3)
```

However for data with a missing date I get the following error `Error: expecting a single value`. I think this is because `dplyr` does not know what to do when it reaches a missing data point.

Doing some research, it seems like `do` is the way to go, but it returns a data frame without any of the values subtracted from one another.

```
df %>%
  filter(location %in% c(4, 'out')) %>% 
  group_by(date, sensor) %>% 
  do(Diff = Temp[location=="4"] - Temp[location=="out"],
            location = first(location)) %>%
  select(1, 2, 4, 3)
```

Is there a way to override dplyr and tell it to return `NA` if it can't find one of the entries to subtract?

Comment: Btw, I get the same error for your data, even though there's no missing date values!

Comment: there are missing values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to return `NA`, the possible option is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(4, 'out')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensor) %>%
    arrange(sensor, location) %>%   
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else diff(Temp), location = first(location))  %>%
    select(1, 2, 4, 3)
#        date sensor location  Diff
#      <fctr>  <dbl>   <fctr> <dbl>
#1 2016-03-24      1        4    21
#2 2016-03-24     16      out    NA
```

and an equivalent option in `data.table` is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[location %in% c(4, 'out')][
     order(sensor, location), .(Diff = if(.N==1) NA_real_ else diff(Temp), 
      location = location[1]), .(date, sensor)][, c(1, 2, 4, 3), with = FALSE]
#          date sensor location Diff
#1: 2016-03-24      1        4   21
#2: 2016-03-24     16      out   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

date <- c("2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24",
          "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24")
location <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, "out", "out")
sensor <- c(1, 16, 1, 16, 1, 16, 1, 1, 16)
Temp <- c(35, 34, 92, 42, 21, 47, 42, 63, 12)

df <- data_frame(date, location, sensor, Temp)

# edge case helper
`%||0%` <- function (x, y) { if (is.null(x) | length(x) == 0) y else x }

df %>%
  filter(location %in% c(4,  'out')) %>%
  mutate(location=factor(location, levels=c("4", "out"))) %>%             # make location a factor 
  arrange(sensor, location) %>%                                           # order it so we can use diff()
  group_by(date,  sensor) %>%
  summarize(Diff = diff(Temp) %||0% NA, location = first(location)) %>% # deal with the edge case
  select(1,  2,  4,  3)
## Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
## Groups: date [1]
## 
##         date sensor location  Diff
##        <chr>  <dbl>   <fctr> <dbl>
## 1 2016-03-24      1        4    21
## 2 2016-03-24     16      out    NA
```